# Java - Recursion - Counting all combinations

Tags: java, recursion, permutation

i had a question regarding counting all possible combinations. For example if i have a recursive method that gives me an output of:
a. 0 0 
b. 0 1
c. 1 0
d. 1 1

in this case i have 8 possible outputs. how should i count them using java?
i tried to use a counter but its giving me 4.

Please help.
Thanks.
here is my code.

```
public static void printAllAssignments(char set[], int k) {
    int n = set.length;
    printAllAssignments(set, "", n, k);
}

// The main recursive method to print all possible strings of length k
 public static void printAllAssignments(char set[], String prefix, int n, int k) {

    // Base case: k is 0, print prefix
    if (k == 0) {
        counterTotalAssignments++;
        System.out.println("Occupancies: " + prefix);
        return;
    }

    // One by one add all characters from set and recursively
    // call for k equals to k-1
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {

        // Next character of input added
        String newPrefix = prefix + set[i];

        // k is decreased, because we have added a new character
        printAllAssignments(set, newPrefix, n, k - 1);

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
 char charSet[] = {'0', '1'};
    int k = 2;
    printAllAssignments(charSet, k);
    System.out.println("Total number of assignments: " + counterTotalAssignments);
}

output:
Occupancies: 00
Occupancies: 01
Occupancies: 10
Occupancies: 11
Total number of assignments: 4
```

Comment: exp(n, k)?! Why count when you can be smarter?

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to count them, when they can be calculated from your input:

```
combinations = exp (possible values per digit, number of digits)
```

If you insist on counting them I'd use the in your case unused return value:

Have the base case return 1 and return the sum of the return values of the recursive calls in the recursive case.

---

I just noticed that your counter is giving you the correct value. Why were you expecting it to be 8?

```
00 // 1.
01 // 2.
10 // 3.
11 // 4.
```

Comment: i know this method bro, but we are not allowed to use x^y method :p

Comment: You could write on yourself, but keeping the restriction that you must count them: You already do, and it's correct. I showed another solution. Do you really need to count possible results, or do you have go count recursive calls?

Comment: well it should return how many assignments exists. 0 , 0 is counted as 2 assignments. and so on. and total is 8 assignments.

Comment: I don't see the mathematical background for this, but since every string has the same length, k, just multiply with k.

Comment: yeah that can work too i guess. i will try it. This is confusing me too, i dont see a point why we are not allowed to use x^y :p